# Circulation around a self-intersecting curve

Tags: vector-analysis, gradient-flows

[image]
Is computing circulation around this curve sensible? In a circuit, electric current flows through intersecting paths - but I haven't seen an instance where it flows within a closed, self-intersecting loop such as that above. 
If it is sensible, what is its interpretation? Also, let me know whether the following statement is accurate: 
"Using the fluid interpretation, circulation is a constant value which indicates the rate at which a fluid immersed in the vector force field would flow."

Comment: It's actually quite common in electric circuits for them to be wired like this or with more intersections, this is where the Kirchoff loop and intersection rules come into play. That's from a physics perspective of course

Comment: Now that you mention it, yes - they're wired like this almost all the time, but a bit more rectangular-ish, so I didn't quite realize xD

But how would this work with water fluids, for example? What would happen at the intersection?

Comment: It's risky to conflate reality with mathematics. If you're dealing with physical, viscous fluid flowing through an actual pipe/tube, I think you'll find that naive approximation of line integrals fails even without self-intersections. ;)

Comment: I maintain my inquiry purely within the mathematical model - which aims to represent reality. The model must, within its own domain, have an interpretation - and I don't see one here. 

Either way, what about my statement in quotations in the original post?